# Index Match in VBA Formula property

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to loop through a range of cells and apply an index match . So, far, the index match is working only for the first row of the range (so its not looping). I am providing the code.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Sheets("REPORT").Select
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Formula "=INDEX('2609'!C:C,MATCH('REPORT'!A2,'2609'!E:E,FALSE))"
```

Comment: Just guessing: you might try and lock `A2` e.g. `MATCH('REPORT'!$A$2,'2609'!E:E,FALSE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

```
Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Formula "=INDEX('2609'!C:C,MATCH('REPORT'!A2,'2609'!E:E,FALSE))"
```

as

```
Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Formula ="=INDEX('2609'!C:C,MATCH('REPORT'!A2,'2609'!E:E,FALSE))"
```

you are missing `=` sign.

Your code can be written as

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REPORT")
    With ws
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Formula = "=INDEX('2609'!C:C,MATCH('REPORT'!A2,'2609'!E:E,FALSE))"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mrig! however, it keeps showing an #N/A to all the cells of the range besides the first one

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas - Are you sure there is match for all other values. If yes kindly check the formulas in `Column C`, it should `=INDEX('2609'!C:C,MATCH(Report!A2,'2609'!E:E,FALSE))` in`C2` then`=INDEX('2609'!C:C,MATCH(Report!A3,'2609'!E:E,FALSE))` in `C3` i.e. `Report!A2,A3,A4,...` should be changing.

Comment: thanks again! I manually checked the values ... from the second row and above it appears a #N/A even for the manual formula.. But there should be a result because I checked them indivudually, and there are matching values ... however the formula is not working.. any idea why ?

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas - If its not working even when formula is entered manually then probably there should be some issue with data though I am sure. So is it possible to share some dummy/sample data of what you have.

Comment: Can We move to conversation and for me to share the file ?

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas - To share file you'll have to upload it online and then you can share the link here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155746/discussion-between-pericles-faliagas-and-mrig).